# Uncaught syntax error when compiling vs browsing in Reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, sbt

I'm compiling my Reactjs application with sbt.

**Browser exception**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

**Compilation error**

```
Parse Error: Line 2: Unexpected token = In C:\Users\martin\Documents\Web Projects\example-app\app\assets\javascripts\nav.jsx:2 1class Nav extends React.Component { 2 static propTypes = { 3 user: React.PropTypes.object 4 }; 5 6 constructor() {
```

**Reason?**

I'm not sure why yet, but the browser (Chrome) likes the syntax one way and the sbt compiler does not.

When I change `static propTypes = {` to `static propTypes: {` the compiler no longer complains, but the browser does.

**Code**

```
    static propTypes: {
        user: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    state: {};
      componentDidMount() {
        $.getJSON("./mock-database/users.json", (json) => {
          this.setState({user: json});
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is probably not setup to enable static class properties.   In most cases it's easier to define your proptypes outside of the class and it should compile just fine.

```
class YourClass extends Component {
  render() {
  } 
}

YourClass.propTypes = {
 user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same with state as well? I'm getting the same exception at ``state: {``

Comment: You can put state in the constructor as `this.state = {};` If your state is empty though you can ignore it.